# How to read complexnumber from excel with Apache Poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi, complex-numbers

I want to read an xlsx file that its content is complexnumber.I use the apache poi. But I do not know how to read complex numbers from Excel by using this library.

Answer (score 1):

Complex numbers are stored in `Excel`cells as strings.

For example the result value of `=COMPLEX(3,4)` will be the string `3+4i`. This can be read via `apache poi` the same way as other string cell values too.

The better approach is using a `DataFormatter` in combination with a `FormulaEvaluator`.

Example:

Excel:

[image]

Java:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

class ExcelReadCOMPLEX {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("COMPLEX.xlsx"));

  FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  Row row = sheet.getRow(1);
  Cell cell;
  for (int c = 0 ; c < 3; c++) {
   cell = row.getCell(c);
   System.out.println(cell.getCellFormula()); //COMPLEX(3,4), IMREAL(A2), IMAGINARY(A2)
   System.out.println(formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator)); //3+4i, 3, 4
  }

  String[] formulas = new String[]{"COMPLEX(5, -6)", "IMREAL(INDEX(A:A, ROW()))", "IMAGINARY(INDEX(A:A, ROW()))"};
  row = sheet.createRow(2);
  for (int c = 0 ; c < 3; c++) {
   cell = row.createCell(c);
   cell.setCellFormula(formulas[c]);
   System.out.println(cell.getCellFormula());
   System.out.println(formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator)); //5-6i, 5, -6
  }

  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

Result printed to `stdout`:

```
COMPLEX(3,4)
3+4i
IMREAL(A2)
3
IMAGINARY(A2)
4
COMPLEX(5, -6)
5-6i
IMREAL(INDEX(A:A, ROW()))
5
IMAGINARY(INDEX(A:A, ROW()))
-6
```

The question is what then? What are you wanting to do with this in `Java`?